# Are there any 'safe' addons to manage browser functionallity?

Tags: firefox, add-on

I'm new to Tor, and would like to ask if three 'cosmetic' Firefox addons - Tab Mix Plus, All-in-one Sidebar, and Scrapbook - pose an anonymity threat?

Comment: // , Could you add some quick links to the addons mentioned? Also, what is an example of the sort of answer you're looking for here, Panoptes?

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to use any addons with Tor. If you want addons then Tor is not the browser for you.
Personally I would never risk Tor's anonymity by using 3rd party addons. That's what Firefox is for. Not Tor

Comment: // , How, exactly, do specific add-ons affect the Tor Browser Button's fingerprint or anonymity? I think this question is more about what sort of effect different add-ons have, and why, rather than a simple y/N.